# How to make format table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I need to display list customers as table as following image by using angularjs but still not find out a solution for it, maybe must use ng-class but don't know how to apply for this case. If everyone have solution please help me.

Condition:

- Gender = Female then textcolor of row will be green
- Age < 20 background color will be orange
- Age > 60 background color will be gray

[image]

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I can generate rows but still not know how to apply format for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
<style> 

 .isteen {  
    background-color: blue;  
 }  

 .isold {  
    background-color: gray;  
 } 

 .isgirl {  
   color: green;  
 }
```

Js

```
<script>  
 var app = angular.module('MyForm', []);  
 app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {  
  $scope.students = [  
        {name: 'Kevin', age: 25, gender: 'boy', phone:'091231232'},  
        {name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'girl',phone:'091231233'},  
        {name: 'Laura', age: 28, gender: 'girl',phone:'091231234'},  
        {name: 'Joy', age: 15, gender: 'girl',phone:'091231235'},  
        {name: 'Mary', age: 28, gender: 'girl',phone:'091231236'},  
        {name: 'Peter', age: 95, gender: 'boy',phone:'091231237'},  
        {name: 'Bob', age: 50, gender: 'boy',phone:'091231238'},  
        {name: 'Erika', age: 27, gender: 'girl',phone:'091231239'},  
        {name: 'Patrick', age: 40, gender: 'boy',phone:'0912312366'},  
        {name: 'Tery', age: 61, gender: 'girl',phone:'0912312355'}  
       ] ;  
 });
```

HTML

```
<table style="min-width: 600px;" >  
   <thead>  
     <tr>  
       <th>No</th>  
       <th>  
        Name
       </th>  
       <th> Age </th>  
       <th >Gender</th> 
        <th>Phone</th>
     </tr>  
   </thead>  
   <tbody>  
     <tr ng-repeat="user in students" ng-class="user.gender=='girl'? 'isgirl':''">  
       <td>  
              {{ $index }}      
       </td>  
       <td>{{ user.name}}</td>  
       <td ng-class="user.age <20?'isteen':user.age >60?'isold':''">{{ user.age}}</td>  
       <td >{{ user.gender}}</td>  
        <td>{{ user.phone}}</td>  
     </tr>  
   </tbody>  
 </table>
```

Edit [at Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QqJAlWTRcy6U9fFd79XO?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can save `customers` in scope and use `ng-repeat` to generate rows.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.Gender }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.Age }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can add custom classes with `ng-class` addnotation for each cell:

```
    <td ng-class="{'className': x.Name == 'Batman'}">{{ customer.Name }}</td>
```

or whole row:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-class="className : customer.Gender == 'Batman'">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-class="greenText : customer.Gender == 'Female'">
  <td>{{customer.No}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.Gender}}</td>
  <td ng-class="{orangeBg : customer.Age < 20, grayBg : customer.Age > 60}">{{customer.Age}}</td>
  <td>{{customer.Phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

'customers' is the list of 'customer' objects.

greenText, orangeBg and grayBg are css classes

Comment: Only answer that gave the OP *everything* that he had asked for. Have a +1.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body class="container" ng-app="">

<style>
  .green-back{
     background: green;
  }
  </style>
  
  <table ng-init="customers=[{name:'name1',age:11, gender:'Male'},
   {name:'name1',age:22, gender:'Female'}]">
  <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
    <td ng-class="{'green-back': customer.gender == 'Female'}">{{ customer.gender }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.age }}</td>
    <td >{{ customer.c }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Use this way. `ng-class` will help you proper give dynamic styles,  i have declared the json array with ng-init and also i have provided the style i have used. this will generate the `td` with `female` gender with green background

```
<style>
    .green-back{
         background: green;
     }
</style>

<table ng-init="customers=[{name:'name1',age:11, gender:'Male'},
 {name:'name1',age:22, gender:'Female'}]">

     <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
         <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
         <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
         <td ng-class="{'green-back': customer.gender == 'Female'}">{{customer.gender }}</td>
         <td>{{ customer.age }}</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```